# Show an Image if a PHP argument proves true

Tags: php, image

I barely know how to use PHP and I can't seem to make my code show an image if a condition proves true. This is the code:

```
<?php
$search=get_search_query();
$first=$search[0];

if ($first=="#"){

}
?>
```

I tried writing this thinking it would work and it didn't:

```
  echo "<html>";
  echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/lujan.jpg'>";
```

Also I tried a code I found which started with the function:  `header()` but it caused a tremendously long error, which said something like header already defined.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used 'double quotes' incorrectly in the echo statement.

Try the following:

```
echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/lujan.jpg' alt='Preview not available' />"
```

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.

Answer (score 0):

You should `var_dump($first)` to know what it contains

check if the condition is really getting true

and also put single quote inside the double quote.

```
if ($first=="#"){
  echo 'yes it is true';
 echo "<img src='http://chusmix.com/Imagenes/grupos/lujan.jpg'>";

}
```

close the `img` tag

Comment: But it is better you should always follow proper way of coding

Answer (score 0):

The part of the query string starting with `#` (so-called "hash") is not being sent to the server. That is, if your page is called like `myblog.com/foo?bar=baz#quux`, you php script will only receive `myblog.com/foo?bar=baz`. You need javascript if you want to handle urls with hashes.